# iOS viewWillDisappear UILabel text property empty?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm new to Swift and try to do some hands on and I ran into something I'm not sure is "normal" behaviour regarding the viewWillDisapear event.

When I look around (read Googling), it's look like viewWillDisapear seems the best place to put code that save your last change in a view. So I put a simple label control with a stepper to change it's value and save into a NSUserDefaults object. The thing is the text property is empty when a got this event in my code. The debug area show that the object is still there but there's no property to explore (and not value then). Is this the normal behavior for UI object present in this view? My actual "workaround" is the use a class instance variable to store this value instead of relying on the text property of the label.

Am I missing something here? Here the code snippet :

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        println("view will disappear...")
        println(self.lblCodeSpeed.text)  // --> blank output?!

        var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        defaults.setObject(self.lblCodeSpeed.text, forKey: "codeSpeed")

        defaults.synchronize()

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it, my label always has value.

Comment: @gabbler, hummm your right..closed XCode and restarted it... bam! value is there?!?!? Ok, forget about this one!